# Как загрузить таблицу с БД в массив и затем сделать выборку с массива?

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных

Доброго времени суток уважаемые.
Есть вопрос, как загнать таблицу из MYSQL в массив а потом делать из массива выборку?

Comment: как обычно.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как загнать таблицу с MYSQL в массив

```
$handle = mysqli_connect($host, $login, $password);
$handle->select_db($database);
$resultset = $handle->query("select * from test");
$arr = [];
while($ass = $resultset->fetch_assoc()) $arr[] = $ass;
$resultset->free();
```

> а потом делать с массива выборку

А вот это уже зависит от того какая выборка из массива нужна и как вы ее собираетесь делать. На практике, например, бывает такое, что при добавлении в запрос `ORDER BY` в `EXPLAIN` вылезает `filesort`, от которого трудно избавиться. Тогда делают выборку в массив, а массив сортируют.

Что именно нужно автору, осталось неизвестным.

**UPDATE**

Нашел на enSO SQL-запрос, который вам нужен. Вот он:

```
SELECT m1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE to_send = m1.to_send) cnt FROM messages m1 LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m1.to_send = m2.to_send AND m1.id < m2.id WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо сделать корректный запрос в БД, а потом с результирующим набором делать необходимые манипуляции.

Answer (score -1):

Получить данные

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
if($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['title'].$row['content'];
}
}
```

Comment: Выборку уже можно делать через if

Comment: Удивительно, но вопрос был совсем про другое.